# Keyboard keys mixed up (y and z) on Win 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, input, qwerty

Configuration:
Lenovo P50 PC
Windows 10 Enterprise

I have a really weird problem. I have 2 keyboard layouts installed English-US (QWERTY) and German (QWERTZ).

All was working fine. Then starting yesterday after a restart smth weird started happening.

When the keyboard is English-US then both the z and the y keyboard key output a 'z'.
When the keyboard is German then both the z and the y keyboard key output a 'y'.

What I have tried is the following (all in vain):

- Removed both keyboard layouts and added them again.
- Uninstalled the keyboard in device manager and restarted the PC.
- I have tried with another physical keyboard (same result). I use the Logitech MK710 wireless.
- I have tried with the actual laptop keyboard (the PC is a laptop) and result is the same so it is not a keyboard hardware issue.
- I have tried the Windows on-screen keyboard and there the keys are fine.

Any other ideas maybe?

---

[image: Keyboard Layout 1]

---

[image: Keyboard Layout 2]